How to extract types of class properties
This is my class
class Game extends BaseModel {
    @column({ isPrimary: true })
    declare id: number
    
    @column()
    declare name: string

    @column()
    declare slug: string
}

I'm trying to build a parser to give me an end result like this
{
    id: {
        type: "string",
        props: {
            isPrimary: true
        }
    },
    name: {
        type: "string"
    },
    slug: {
        type: "string"
    },
}

The BaseModel provides a static map where I can find all the columns with the properties from the decorator. But I do not have the types
I haven't found anything that I can use without instantiating the class with values. But I cannot do that because I'm trying to make this parser dynamic so it can handle any model I throw at it

It is impossible at runtime, since types are erased after compilation. Do you mean your parser should analyze your code before compilation?

this is a Adonis JS app. I'm trying to have a description of the models in the manner I've described. Ideally I would run a command and generate a .json file with the descriptions. I am not looking to have this inside a method that is called inside the running app

Then you are probably looking for TS transformers, which statically analyze your TS code as AST, giving you access to types. ts-morph is a widely used wrapper library for such task. If that fits your need, I can make a more detailed answer if I have time.

that looks promising. I will give it a go and send you a message if i don't succeed. thank you
